# FFmpeg, videotoolbox and avplayer in iOS

Tags: ffmpeg, avplayer, decoding, decoder

I have a question how these things are connected and what they exactly do.

FYI, I have a few experience about video player and encoding and decoding.

In my job I deal udp streaming from server and take it with ffmpeg and decodes it and draw it with openGL. And also using ffmpeg for video player.

These are the questions...

**1. Only ffmpeg can decodes UDP streaming (encoded with ffmpeg from the server) or not?**

I found some useful information about **videotoolbox** which can decode streaming with hardware acceleration in iOS. so could I also decode the streaming from the server with videotoolbox?

**2. If it is possible to decode with videotoolbox (I mean if the videotoolbox could be the replacement for ffmpeg), then what is the videotoolbox source code in ffmpeg? why it is there?**

In my decoder I make AVCodecContext from the streaming and it has hwaccel and hwaccel_context field which set null both of them. I thought this videotoolbox is kind of API which can help ffmpeg to use hwaccel of iOS. But it looks not true for now...

**3. If videotoolbox can decode streaming, Does this also decode for H264 in local? or only streaming possible?**

AVPlayer is a good tool to play a video but if videotoolbox could replace this AVPlayer then, what's the benefit? or impossible?

**4. FFmpeg only uses CPU for decoding (software decoder) or hwaccel also?**

When I play a video with ffmpeg player, CPU usage over 100% and Does it means this ffmpeg uses only software decoder? or there is a way to use hwaccel?

Please understand my poor english and any answer would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: on hardware && ffmpeg   , see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Only ffmpeg can decodes UDP streaming (encoded with ffmpeg from the server) or not?**

I don't think so, since `videotoolbox` can do that too.

**2. If it is possible to decode with videotoolbox (I mean if the videotoolbox could be the replacement for ffmpeg), then what is the videotoolbox source code in ffmpeg? why it is there?**

There is a solution which could use `ffmpeg` to read the data from `tcp socket` and transfer it to `videotoolbox`.

This solution avoids the high CPU usage when using only `ffmpeg` and also avoids some faults from using only `vdeotoolbox` such as delays from reading the data from socket.

**3. If videotoolbox can decode streaming, Does this also decode for H264 in local? or only streaming possible?**

`videotoolbox` could play for both local and streaming. (correct me if I'm wrong)

**4. FFmpeg only uses CPU for decoding (software decoder) or hwaccel also?**

Yes, `ffmpeg` uses CPU only which is `software codec` while `videotoolbox` is `hardware codec`.